# How to stay on same tab (bootstrap) after create (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I use the following code to redirect to the where the form is after Create:

```rb
  if @book.save 
    redirect_to :home_index
```

I also have bootstrap vertical tab, where all the tabs share the same url (home/index). On each tab is a form to create and list what's been created.

So after I create on the first tab, I get back to the first tab.

My problem is that when I create on the second, third, etc. tabs, I also get back to the first tab. I want to stay on the third tab.

While there are some questions on SO related to this, they are all for jQuery, PHP, and such and, knowing only Rails, I am finding them hard to use. How can I do this with Rails?

In case it would be useful, the tabs code from bootstrap:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of ways to achieve this:

1. trigger tab creation with an ajax request, then respond from the controller with the html for the new tab and insert it in the DOM, then switch to it on the client when the ajax response is received. or...
2. javascript invoked on page load exposed the tab by inspecting html query string. e.g. www.mypage.com?tab=foo_tab opens foo_tab on page load. In the controller, redirect to the page with the desired tab specified in the query after creation.

I would choose the first method, b/c the user experience would be better than a new page load.